Is there a space-efficient way to store non rectangular raster data?
If you collect very high resolution data over a meandering path like a road or river a rectangular raster would be very inefficient as a very large fraction of the raster would be no-data pixels.
Is there a better, simple way of storing and retrieving data other than to split into thousands of smaller blocks?  eg break it up into sections of along and cross sectional data of a polyline of the centreline path?

"Best" questions are intrinsically opinion-based, which don't fit well with our Focused question/Best answer model. In theory, we have [Chat], but Chat doesn't see as much traffic as the main Q&A site, so you might be better off seeking opinions in a true discussion forum.

While a raw raster would indeed be huge and contain large areas of no-data pixels, compression algorithms would reduce the storage space significantly to the point that it's not obvious that the overhead of a specialized storage structure would be much more space-efficient.

If it's about storing the information, why would a vector format suit your needs ?

There's also database backed solutions such as rasdaman and open datacube

If you have a sparse grid then a compact representation may be to store (i, j, Z) triples, and a lookup of i (column numbers) to X-coordinates, and j (row numbers) to Y-coordinates. This is a fairly common "sparse" representation of a matrix.
For a NxM grid with P present pixels, this takes of the order of 3P values compared to NxM values for the full grid. At some point the sparseness loses the storage benefit, at the point where 3P > NxM, or P > (NxM)/3, when your grid has 1/3 or more locations with values.
This is for an in-memory format - rasters on-disk will have likely been saved using compression algorithms. I don't know of any GIS that works with in-memory sparse rasters, there are packages in R that can do operations with sparse matrices though.
